# How to get the ID from the table which is not mention EndDate

Tags: sql-server-2012

How to get the name from the table which is not having EndDate

in the above pic i need to get D and G details from the table ,
( To understand mOre:

A, C,D,G are having end date, and A, C are again started, but D and G is not started,  so from the query i need to get the name  D and G

the code i used is not works for it

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    SubInventoryID int ,
    SubInventoryName varchar(20),
    RolesName varchar(20),
    StartDate date,
    EndDate date
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(30,'RIF-Teller','Teller', '2016-12-27', '2017-01-23'),
(30,'RIF-Teller','Teller', '2016-12-08', NULL),
(30,'RIF-Teller','Teller', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-05'),
(31,'RIF-Teller','Teller', '2017-01-05', NULL),
(24,'MHQ-Teller','Teller', '2016-09-20', '2017-01-23'),
(24,'MHQ-Teller','Teller', '2016-08-01', '2017-01-05'),
(24,'MHQ-Teller','Teller', '2017-01-05', NULL)
```

Query

```
SELECT UP.SubInventoryID,S.SubInventoryName SubInventoryName,RolesName,UP.StartDate StartDate,
                 UP.EndDate EndDate ,  case  when UP.EndDate IS null then 'Occupied' else 'Closed' End As  Vacancy 
           FROM [View_Alx_UserPosition] UP
                       Inner join ALX_Branches B ON B.BranchID= UP.BranchID    
                       Inner join ALX_SubInventories S ON S.SubInventoryID=UP.SubInventoryID  WHERE   UP.RolesName Like '%Teller%'
                     
           union

           SELECT distinct(UP.SubInventoryID),S.SubInventoryName SubInventoryName, '' FullName, '' RolesName,NUll StartDate,
                          NUll EndDate,'Free' as vacancy
              FROM [View_Alx_UserPosition]  UP
                    Inner join ALX_Branches B ON B.BranchID= UP.BranchID
                    Inner join ALX_SubInventories S ON S.SubInventoryID=UP.SubInventoryID 
                          WHERE UP.EndDate IS NOT NULL ANd UP.RolesName Like '%Teller%'
                                AND NOT EXISTS
                                (
                                    SELECT 1
                                    FROM [View_Alx_UserPosition]  UP1
                                    WHERE  UP1.SubInventoryID =  UP.SubInventoryID
                                    AND UP1.StartDate >= UP.EndDate
                                   -- AND UP1.EndDate IS NOT NULL
                                )
```

[image]

Comment: why D and G did not started yet? seems they have the same start date and end date?

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ID int identity(1,1),
    Name char(1),
    StartDate date,
    EndDate date
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('A', '2016-04-04', '2017-04-03'),
('B', '2016-04-04', NULL),
('C', '2016-04-04', '2017-04-03'),
('D', '2016-04-04', '2017-04-03'),
('E', '2016-04-04', NULL),
('F', '2016-04-04', NULL),
('G', '2016-04-04', '2017-04-03'),
('C', '2017-04-03', NULL),
('A', '2017-04-03', NULL)
```

The query:

```
SELECT Name
FROM @T vu1
WHERE EndDate IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM @T vu2
    WHERE vu2.Name = vu1.Name
    AND vu2.StartDate >= vu1.EndDate
)
```

Results:

```
Name
D
G
```

### First version

Assuming I understand the question, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT Name
FROM View_User vu1
WHERE EndDate IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM View_User vu2
    WHERE vu2.Name = vu1.Name
    AND vu2.StartDate >= vu1.EndDate
    AND vu2.EndDate IS NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: See my edited answer. If you would have posted the sample data as I did in the answer, I could have tested my answer before posting it. Please post sample data as DDL+DML in your future questions.

Comment: I had posted the code and the answer , in the above which is updated, in the image i have marked some rows , it showing the occupied one is free . and i have pasted my code (which is developed according to your code format)

Comment: Yes, but still no DDL+DML for sample data. even worst, your sample data is now a lot more data and doesn't fit the text of the question anymore. Please edit the question to include the minimal sample data needed to understand the problem, as create and insert statements so that we could answer the question.

Comment: I had Updated the code and details in the above question , i think now u can help me i have marked in the image data. which is duplicated

Comment: Ok, that's better, but now you need to edit the text of the question as well to tell us the rules according to your sample data. What you marked are rows without a startDate and without an endDate, that's not what the text said....

Comment: the marked one is the free which is the second query  result ie , the code under the union,  the first one is the code showing all data which is occupied and closed. / so after union it shows the occupied subinventory name ,  showing it is free in the code under the union. ( ie, followed accoring your code in the answer)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand it at all. Please explain the criteria to choose the records you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139931/discussion-between-dona-susan-issac-and-zohar-peled).

Comment: i had mentioned the result i the chat session